# Requiring mongoose in node

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am concerned that-

when i require mongoose in one module and configure in same, and when i create schema and module in another module just adding var mongoose = require('mongoose') and work in mongoose with same configuration, how is that possible?? it works though. But i am confused how it worked. doesn't that mean different instance of mongoose???

I tried to do 
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

in different page and tried to run but it encounters error, i.e configuration in not same, why is that, is't this same as requiring mongoose in two different module and using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of node.js's [module caching](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching), every call to `require('mongoose')` will return the same object.

The behavior you're seeing with that express code is because you're calling `express()` as a function which creates a separate express app each time it's called.

Comment: This is correct. The first time you require a module in node that module becomes stored in a cache located at `require.cache`. If you [remove a key from that cache object](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_require_cache) then that module will be reloaded the next time you call `require`. The Express module is cached too, but as Johnny said, you're calling it like a function when you instantiate it and Express is coded to return a new instance when you do that.